# Ethernet <-> Thunderbolt 2 <-> USB-C : What speed?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, ethernet

Over a lazy weekend, I find myself wanting to connect my fairly new MacBook Pro, with its USB-C connections, to wired ethernet coming off my cable box. Nominal cable speed is 200Mbps; I regularly measure speeds of up to 250Mbps.

However, unfortunately I do not have a direct Ethernet to USB-C. And -- re: lazy weekend -- I can't be bothered to drive to a store to buy one (e.g. this [Belkin](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJKF2ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter)). However, rummaging around my box of ancient, obsolete, and otherwise weird crap, I find I *do* have:

1. An Apple A1433 [Ethernet female to Thunderbolt 2 male](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD463LL/A/thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter) connector; and
2. An Apple A1790 [Thunderbolt 3 female to USB-C male](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) connector

Bolted together, those two give me Ethernet female to USB-C male.

Trouble is that, while that does work in terms of connectivity, and while each of the components should be well capable of handling the nominal 200Mpbs coming in from the street (and, as I say, I often get up to 250Mbps), it's only giving me around 60Mbps.

**So, any idea what part of the setup could be causing the speed degradation?**

Comment: Devices are only as fast as the slowest item in the chain, which in this case appears to be the Ethernet

Comment: Look at System Prefs>Network>Ethernet [whichever is green] then Advanced>Hardware. If that's set to Automatically, the areas below will be greyed out, but will show the correct negotiated speed, etc. Let us know what it says.

Comment: @MatthewBarclay, you're right that, my cable box ethernet, at 200Mpbs, is certainly the slowest piece of kit. But while I see most of that 200Mbps if I connect *wirelessly*, I see only 60Mbps if I connect by *wire* -- i.e. via the A1433<->A1790<->USB-C chain. So the problem isn't with my ethernet per se; it seems to be with my *wired connection* to that ethernet. But what?

Comment: That doesn't really add any new information. Whilst you're doing the check I asked about yesterday, you could also see if any of your ethernet sockets has a light system… green would be 1000baseT, yellow 100 or less. You also haven't told us what the ethernet device is - just in case that's the limiting factor.